# how to insert an image in a specific location using Google Docs API

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs

I am managing to insert text into specific location in a document using `batchUpdate`, But I couldn't find any resource to how to do the same only with images. Any documentation about the matter will be highly appreciated. My text replacing function looks like that:

```
async function updateDoc(docs, auth, documentId) {
    try {
        await docs.documents.batchUpdate({
            auth,
            documentId: documentId,
            requestBody: {
                requests
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Will be great to have something similar for images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to insert an image to Google Document with Google Docs API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Document with Docs API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

When it inserts an image to Google Document with Docs API, in the current stage, it uses URL of the image. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please use `requests` for your script.

```
const requests = [{
  insertInlineImage: {
    location: {index: 1},
    uri: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png"
  }
}];
```

- In this request body, the logo of stackoverflow is inserted to the top of body in the Google Document.

#### Note:

- When you want to insert the specific index, at first, please retrieve the index using the method of documents.get in Docs API.
- If you want to use the uploaded image in Google Drive, please use the direct link of the URL in the Google Drive. In this case, please share the image and insert it with the above request body.

#### Reference:

- [InsertInlineImageRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertinlineimagerequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much! You understood my question perfectly and the solution you provided is going to work. However, I wonder if there is a way to get it by using something like `replaceAllText` request? So I wont need to search the index needed to insert the image but I could just replace a given string with the image?

Comment: You know what? your solution works great! I will just combine it with `docs.documents.get` to extract the index I need as you suggested and it will be good enough. Thanks (:

Comment: @obiwankenoobi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Is there any way to insert images to google doc from your local system - as in not from a publicly accessible URL?

Comment: @Siddharth Is this library useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/node-gdoctableapp

Comment: I am working on a Java project. I want to upload PNGs along with other text in the google doc and I don't see any such library from Google Doc APIs on this. Do you know of any?

Comment: @Siddharth Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. I have created such library for golang, node.js and python. I deeply apologize for this situation, again.

Comment: No problem. If you have any resource which points to how this problem can be solved, do ping here. I will keep exploring till then.

Comment: @Siddharth Thank you for replying. I created such libraries by checking the official document of Docs API. But if this was not the direction you want, I apologize again.